# How to manage multiple events in a single method

Tags: java, android, andengine

(This is probably more of a Java-question in general than an AndEngine-specific question, but I added both tags to be on the safe side)

In AndEngine, touch events are catched by implementing IOnSceneTouchListener and then adding this method:

```
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene scene, TouchEvent event) {
   ...
}
```

Within this method, one can check for the events by testing `event.isActionUp()` (user has touched the screen), `event.isActionDown()` (user has released the screen) and `event.isActionMove()` (user is moving the touch).

Currently I'm making a game where I need to be distinct of special cases, like `if (isActionDown() && isActionMove())`, `if (userHasMoved && isActionUp()` and the particular.

My current code works, but is not very beautiful. Snippet of it:

```
if ( (!hubIsClicked) && (!touchMoveIsDone) && event.isActionDown()) {
  System.out.println("isActionDown, puzzlepiece");
  touchMoveIsDone = false;
  touchedBoardBlock = getBoardBlockFromPixelCoordinate(X, Y);
} else if ( (!hubIsClicked) && (!touchMoveIsDone) && event.isActionMove()) {
  // Puzzle piece
  System.out.println("isActionMove, puzzlepiece");
  ..
}
```

Here, `boolean hubIsClicked` and `boolean touchMoveIsDone` are global class variables. I don´t think this is a good way to flag for distinct cases, but it's the only way I know of since my Java-fu is not high enough.

Question: I'm asking for how to make these checks better, perhaps by not using global variables at all. Is there a "the real Java way" to do this?

Comment: To suggest you what to improve it's necessary to know what the purpose of `hubIsClicked` and `touchMoveIsDone` global fields is and where they are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start some of your conditions are common, so you can share that part of the code, e.g.

```
if ( !hubIsClicked && !touchMoveIsDone)
{
  if (event.isActionDown())
  {  
    System.out.println("isActionDown, puzzlepiece");
    touchMoveIsDone = false;
    touchedBoardBlock = getBoardBlockFromPixelCoordinate(X, Y);
  }
  else if (event.isActionMove())
  {
    // Puzzle piece
    System.out.println("isActionMove, puzzlepiece");
    ..
  }
}
```

You then talk about global variables, but don't show them. Be careful what you mean; in Java, there are static variables which exist for all instances of the class, and then instance variables on a per-instance basis. I have taken what you said to mean static. In your case, you are correct that use of static variables here is typically incorrect and can be improved upon.

You would not typically expect a listener itself to maintain state; that is, if you wrote the listener implementation in a separate class, it would not have any class or instance variables. However inherently to be of use, the listener must belong to someone, e.g. an activity, and it is reasonable for this owner to maintain state and the listener to use it.

I've shown that below as an example:

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements IOnSceneTouchListener
{  
    private boolean hubIsClicked = false;

    private boolean touchMoveIsDone = false;

    public MyActivity( ... )
    {
        //blah
    }

    @Override  
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent)  
    {  
       // Do something on scene touched event  
       return false;  
    } 
}
```

The variables belong to the **instance** of the activity, and as the listener code does too, it can make use of them.

You should always bear in mind the lifetime of the owner, and the relationship between it and the information you want to hold; for instance, Activities are destroyed when the UI goes away, but you probably don't need to hold this state for any longer.

Note that you can do much the same thing if your listener is an inner class rather than incorporated using 'implements', i.e.:

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseGameActivity
{  
    private boolean hubIsClicked = false;

    private boolean touchMoveIsDone = false;

    public MyActivity( ... )
    {
       //example only
       addMyExampleListener( new IOnSceneTouchListener()
       {
          @Override  
          public void onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent)  
          {  
             //example only
             MyActivity.this.hubIsClicked = true;
          } 
       });
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: On the other hand, sharing common conditions creates nested code which is less readable and maintainable. Good luck when you want to change or debug your game logic after a couple of months. After I went all the way to hell and back the last time, I just reformatted the code so that all the conditions are beautifully aligned in columns and in correct order. It's my own little Japanese rock garden :-)

Comment: Very true - I guess it's a case-by-case value judgement based on the underlying logic and how likely the resulting code is to change.